# C# - Sort list of strings by instances of a specified character?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, collections

If i want to sort a List of strings (say 15 strings) by the amount of a  specified character (lets say "b" in this case), how can I do this? The order of strings which does not contain the specified character does not matter.

> Example: "amy", "bob", "lee", "bret", this should be
> sorted like this:
>
> 1. "bob"
> 2. bret
> 3. amy
> 4. lee

My guess is that I'll have to create a new class inherited by the IComparer, but beyond that im not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Code so far, if it matters:

```
List<string> str = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}: ", i + 1);
                str.Add(Console.ReadLine());               
            }
```

Comment: Where's your attempt at sorting the way you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a class is possible indeed but with `linq` you can ask yourself if it's really required

```
List<string> listOfNames = new List<string>();
listOfNames.Add("bob");
listOfNames.Add("bret");
listOfNames.Add("amy");
listOfNames.Add("lee");

// sort the string by the count of character of B or b
var sorted = listOfNames.OrderBy(name => name.Count(c => c == 'b' || c == 'B')).ToList();
```

Comment: So simple, would you look at that! Much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer using Linq is the one that is most clear I think but you can also use a comparer.  And using the List.Sort does avoid creating a new list.

You can create a custom comparer specifically for the case your after - counting chars.  Or you can create a generic one that uses a lambda.  The second is more fun so I'll show that one.

```
    class AnonymousComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
    {
        Func<T, T, int> compare;

        public AnonymousComparer(Func<T, T, int> compare)
        {
            this.compare = compare;
        }

        public int Compare([AllowNull] T x, [AllowNull] T y)
        {
            return this.compare(x, y);
        }

        public static implicit operator AnonymousComparer<T>(Func<T,T,int> compare) 
            => new AnonymousComparer<T>(compare);
    }
```

Once you have that then you can just supply a lambda that would do the comparison.  This uses a simple local function to dry out the character comparison.

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        List<string> myStrings = new List<string>(
                                new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", });

        bool IsMyLetter(char ch) => ch == 'e' || ch == 'E';

        myStrings.ForEach((s) => Console.WriteLine(s));

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nafter sort\n");

        myStrings.Sort((lhs, rhs) => rhs.Count(x => IsMyLetter(x)) - lhs.Count(x => IsMyLetter(x)));

        myStrings.ForEach((s) => Console.WriteLine(s));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this more in-depth code, very interesting way to solve it.